# How to open camera from an row of RecyclerView and return result in onActivityResult?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, camera

I need to open camera and take picture then get the result as file path and save it somewhere .In activity it is simple but in RecyclerView its a little bit hard to do I guess
its a nested RecyclerView by the way ,may not be that important but may be helpfull

Does any body know how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do this is to use call back to parent activity and do all open camera related task there